# I am trying to use VLOOKUP to match the content of two different column on two different table, however its not working

Tags: excel, excel-formula

A simple table of students and calss, and whether they can go home alone

[image]

And another table

[image: Another table but home alone is empty]

I wish to use VLOOKUP becuase its not case senstive which means on the real dataset I ma handling it would be more useful, and I wish to match Name of Table 1 to Name of Table 2, and Class of Table 2 to Class of Table 2, however all our attempts have failed in to either error or the result give as using a double VLOOKUP, whats the best way to approach this ? Thanks in advance

Expecting the result of Column 3 from table 1 and we tried double VLOOKUP, and VLOOKUP ( [Column1]&[Column2].....), it gives wrong results or just errors